# Kivy App not optimised for iPhone X, Xs and Xs Max

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, kivy-language

I've created an app using `Kivy` which I've successfully packaged for `iOS`. I can successfully run the app in the `Xcode simulator`. However, when I run it in the simulators for iPhone X, Xs and Xs Max all the widgets in my app are squished together. See the following pic:

[image: Screenshot]

I have already added `LaunchImages` to my `Xcode` project, which I had previously been advised may fix the problem, however, the scaling is still wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need a minimum row height if that's in a GridLayout